# напишите функцию funcReverse, которая эмулирует работу метода reverse

Tags: javascript

Напишите функцию f13, которая эмулирует работу метода reverse. Т.е. создает новый массив на основе d13 с обратным порядком элементов и выводит в out-13.

Comment: В условии противоречие - метод `reverse()` не создает новый массив.

Comment: Если ответ данный участником @denis640kb является правильным. Отметьте его как верный ответ!

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте ваши попытки решения задачи, чтобы мы могли вас направить, или подсказать где ошибка. Решать здесь за вас вряд-ли кто станет. За это минус

Answer (score 2):

На данном сайте принято выкладывать собственные попытки решения задачи.
Решение задач за авторов не привествуется. 
Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, в будущем сначала попробовать решить проблему самостоятельно, а затем задать вопрос, приложив свои попытки в виде кода. 
Так как Вы новый участник - добавил один из вариантов.

```js
    var d13 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    function f13(array) {
        var out13 = [];
        for (let i=array.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            out13.push(array[i]);
        }
        return out13
    }
    console.log(f13(d13));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let d13 = [6, 0, 22, 1, 4, 76];

function f13() {
    let b = [];
    for (let i = d13.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        b.push(d13[i]);
    }
    d13 = b;
    showArr('.out-13', d13);
}

document.querySelector('.b-13').onclick = f13;`
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
// Это функция для вывода    
function showArr(domElem, arr) {
        let out = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += arr[i] + ' ';
        }
        document.querySelector(domElem).innerHTML = out;
}   

 

let d13 = [6, 0, 22, 1, 4, 76];

function f13() {
    let a = []; // Создаем пустой массив

    for (i = d13.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { // Запускаем обратный цикл
        a.push(d13[i]); // метод PUSH - добавляет один/несколько элементов в конец массива
    }

    d13 = a; // Изменяем массив 'd13' на новый массив 'a'

    showArr('.out-13', d13);
}

document.querySelector('.b-13').onclick = f13;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал так:

1. Получаем индекс последнего элемента и создаем новый пустой массив
2. Пробегаемся по массиву d13 и каждому i-тому индексу массива t13 присваиваем последнее значение массива d13
3. Уменьшаем lastIndex (1 - d13.length - 1; 2 - d13.length - 2; 3 - d13.length - 3 и тд)

   ```
    let d13 = [6, 0, 22, 1, 4, 76];

    function f13() {
       let lastIndex = d13.length - 1
       let t13 = []

       for (let i = 0; i < d13.length; i++) {
           t13[i] = d13[lastIndex]
           lastIndex--
       }


    d13 = t13 }
   ```